# Convergence in $L^p(U)$ of smooth functions acted on by a $C^1$ function with $|U|<\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lp-spaces

Assume $U$ is bdd and $G:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$ with $G'$ bdd. If we have smooth $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p(U)$, do we necessarily have that $Gf_n \rightarrow Gf$ in $L^p(U)$?

I feel if $U$ was connected I could just apply the MVT, but as this is not necessarily the case I'm at a loss.

Comment: You do not need the geometry of $U$. You apply the MVT to $G$, which is defined on the real line.

Comment: My god I'm so dumb! Why the hell was getting worked up about the behavior of $Gf_n$ on $U$? As you've pointed out, I should just consider $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**. Establish the following inequality:
$$\lvert G(y)-G(z)\rvert^p\le C\lvert y-z\rvert^p,$$
for a constant $C>0$ that is independent on $y$ and $z$.

Comment: As $G$ is defined on all $\mathbb{R}$, for any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, we have from the MVT that $|G(y)-G(z)|=|G'(\gamma)||y-z|\leq C|y-z|$, where $C$ is a bound for $G'$. The inequality then follows from the monotonicity of $x^p$ when $p>0$.

Answer (score -1):

Forget $C^1$ and smoothness. Just let $G$ be any bounded measurable function on $U$ and assume $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(U).$ Then $\|Gf_n-Gf\|_p \le \|G\|_\infty\|f_n - f\|_p \to 0.$

Comment: Can someone propose a theory as to why this was downvoted?

Comment: I think that there are two problems with this. First, the composition $G\circ f_n$ does not make sense if $G$ is defined on $U$. (And even if it made, measurability of $G\circ f_n$ would not follow automatically). Second, if $G$ is only bounded, then the result is false: take for example $U=(0, 1)$ and $G(y)=\operatorname{sign}(y)$, $f_n(x)=(-1)^n\lvert x \rvert^n$.

Comment: Well thank you. I would never have figured out $Gf_n = G\circ f_n$ was intended.